# UART communication with Hex-Code

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, hex, uart, serial-communication

I connected my Raspberry Pi with a microcontroller to see if I can get them to communicate via UART.

However, some of my communication works, some of it doesn´t:

```
import serial
import time
import binascii

port = serial.Serial("dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200,timeout=1.0)

while True:

    arr1 = bytearray([0xAA,0x90,0x24,0x86])
    print (arr1)

    port.write(arr1)
    print (port.write(arr1)

    answ = port.read()
    print (answ)
```

and here´s the answer I get:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
 [GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>==================================RESTART=================================
>>>
bytearray(b'\xaa\x90$\x85')
4
b'\xaa'
bytearray(b'\xaa\x90$\x85')
4
b'\x90'
bytearray(b'\xaa\x90$\x85')
4
b'$'
bytearray(b'\xaa\x90$\x85')
4
b'\x85
```

Why does it "kill" my 0x24 ???

I need this to communicate with the microcontroller I´m using. 
The array is supposed to be a "start-Transmitting" -code.

Comment: in ASCII, $ is 0x24 ... It just chooses to display the character value because it can.

Comment: well that makes sense... Thanks! 
I guess it will still send the right bytes?

Comment: Yes it will send the correct bytes.

Comment: is there a way I can undo this? problem is I sometimes get false values because of this

Comment: As I said before, this doesn't influence the data that get sent nor what gets received, so if communication fails, this probably isn't the issue as this is just a presentation issue. Are you sure that the code that handles the received data is correct?

Comment: problem is it converts a 0x66 to "f" which is correct. But it also converts 0x660x66 to "ff". I have trouble reading this, because "f""f" eqals (15 15) but "ff" equals (255)

Comment: There are several questions here on SO concerning formatted printing of hex data. You can try `print (''.join('{:02x} '.format(byte) for byte in answ))` to get a hex-only space separated printed line.